# Does Qt's moc/C++11 have an equivalent of C#'s nameof() operator?

Tags: c#, c++, qt, c++11, nameof

Does Qt's moc/C++11 have an equivalent of C#'s [`nameof()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx) operator? Qt has the moc system which is/does some kind of reflection but I can't figure out how get the variable name like C#'s [`nameof()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx). Is this possible?

Comment: You could use a macro for it if it suits you. Dedicated reflection support in the language is still a ways off.

Comment: kind of hacky, you mean like that `#define NAMEOF(s) #s` ?

Comment: Pretty much, and per the comment, any solution must be kind of hacky for now.

Answer (score 3):

If your compiler supports C++17, then this library should do everything you want:
https://github.com/Neargye/nameof

See some more examples from the library author at https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/b3spr5/nameof_operator_for_modern_c_simple_name_of_a/

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with C++ 11, because it is only possible with language / compiler support. It also has nothing to do with reflection (at run time) because it gives you the name of an identifier during compile time.